# How to have a drop-down list where the default text cannot be selected?

Tags: html, css

For example, a drop-down list that has the options 1,2 and 3 but has the default text "Make a selection..." without that being a selectable option.

If that's confusing [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66Tbz/). Basically, I don't want you to see "make a selection..." in that example when you click on the drop down.  Just 1,2 and 3.

I assume it could be done with some javascript but that seems hackish.

Code:

```
<select>
    <option>make a selection...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you not just include them in an `<optgroup>`, using the `label` attribute? http://jsfiddle.net/66Tbz/1/

Comment: No the default text needs to be `make a selection`

Comment: Are you ruling out javascript?

Comment: See Ann L's message below.

Comment: @MikeBrant - Not ruling out, but keeping it as my last resort.

Comment: @BenM - saw it.  Won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you can do this using `display:none`:

```
<select>
    <option style="display:none">make a selection...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/66Tbz/2/

Comment: +1 because I had no idea you could `display:none` an `option` tag.

Answer (score 8):

```
<select>
    <option selected="true" disabled="true" >make a selection...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Et4VH/

Comment: +1, this is much closer.  I would prefer to keep "make a selection" out of the drop down list entirely, but it sounds like this might be the closest I can get.

Comment: you could remove it with script once they have changed away from it..
http://jsfiddle.net/Et4VH/3/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<select>
    <option disabled="true" >make a selection...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

If that won't work for you, you might have to resort to Javascript, intercepting clicks and canceling them.

ETA:  Or perhaps combine them:  when clicking on the dropdown, disable the "make a selection" option, ensuring the user can only select one of the other options.  The challenge would be to find an event to trigger enabling "make a selection" again.

ETA:  Well, the following would probably be at the outer limits of "reasonable to spend time on", but I include it for completeness:  You could build a "control" that consisted of a label and a hidden listbox, with a graphic to the right of the label to trigger the visibility of the list box.  You'd need javascript, and it would be a nuisance to get the appearance quite right, but it could do exactly what you've described.

But if you get to that point, you might as well just script up some click handlers for a regular dropdown, and tweak its behavior.

Comment: No, unfortunately I need to have "make a selection" as the default text.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `disabled` attribute as Ann suggested, but then the default would not be visible per default anymore.

Use a `<label>` to recommend the selection, do not use a meaningless `<option>` for that.

```
<label for="foo">Select something</label>
<select name="foo" id="foo">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have to include a meaningless `option` or else I am making one of the options default which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" disabled="true" >make a selection...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a validation javascript function and display a error if the user has not selected any option

```
<form onSubmit="validate()">
<select>
    <option>make a selection...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an inline style, (assuming an id of "selectid" on the select object) why not set `#selectid > option:first-child{ display: none; }` ?

I forked your fiddle.  (heh, heh)

http://jsfiddle.net/qV9kp/

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled="true">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```